# Probability defective process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Certain mechanical pieces undergo two independent processes by two distinct machines A and B. Stain A introduces defects in 5% of the processed pieces. a) Knowing that 7% of the final pieces are defective (ie that they have undergone both processes), calculate the value of the probability P (DB) that machine B introduces defects. b) If a randomly selected final piece is defective, calculate the probability that it has suffered defects from both machines. To carry out the procedure, use the following events: DA = {Machine A has introduced a defect} DB = {Machine B has introduced a defect} D = {The final piece is defective} {Hint: first express D using DA and DB}

I found that $ P(D_B) = 0,09 $ that’s because $ P(D) = P(D|D_A ) P(D_A) + P(D|D_B) P(D_B) $ but I think this is not correct because I also should have $ + P(D|AB) P(AB) $ but I don’t understand how to find this , to find after $P_B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(D_A) = 0.05, P(D) = 0.07$ and we need to find $P(D_B)$.

There are $3$ ways for a product to be defective - defect by machine $A$, defect by machine $B$ or by both. There is only one way for the product to be non-defective - no defect introduced by either of the machines. So we can go about our calculation in two ways. I will use the latter.

$(1-P(D_A)) \times (1-P(D_B)) = 1 - P(D)$

i.e $0.95 \times (1-P(D_B)) = 0.93 \implies P(D_B) \approx 0.021$

Now to find the conditional probability please note that

$P(D_A \cap D_B) = P(D_A) \times P(D_B)$ and you already know $P(D)$.

Comment: I understood the first part and , I hope , the advice you gave me for the second part but now I don’t know the values of $ P(D|D_B) $ and $ P(D|D_A) $ ? So how I can find the value of $ P(D|D_A D_B) $ necessary to find $ P( D_A D_B | D ) that the problem ask me ?

Comment: @ElenaMartini You should look at it as $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B)$. $A$ is event that a piece has defect from both machines (given it is finally defective, which is obvious) and $B$ is event that the piece is finally defective regardless of which machine (or both) it came from. So in this cases, the desired probability should simply be $P(D_A \cap D_B) /P(D)$. You know both.

Comment: Thank you so so much!